# accurate position of value in slider in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have a slider with unequal dividers as shown on the image:
[image]

The value shown on the slider is 2.5 and it looks like it's halfway to 9 (bigger than 4.5). How can I adjust the positining of the value to be accurate to it's limits?

```
Widget buildNutritionalInfoSlider(String category, double value) {
  int max = 0;
  List<int> limits = [0, 9, 18, 31, 45];

  if (category == "calories") {
    limits = [800, 560, 360, 160, 0];
    max = 800;
  } else if (category == "sodium") {
    limits = [900, 630, 360, 180, 0];
    max = 900;
  } else if (category == "fats") {
    limits = [10, 7, 4, 2, 0];
    max = 10;
  } else if (category == "sugars") {
    limits = [45, 31, 18, 9, 0];
    max = 45;
  } else if (category == "protein" || category == "fibers") {
    limits = [18, 9, 0]; // Updated limits for protein and fibers
    max = 18;
  }

  // Implement your slider widget here
  return SliderTheme(
    data: SliderThemeData(
      trackHeight: 0.0,
      thumbShape: TriangleShape(),
      trackShape: GradientRectSliderTrackShape(
        limits: limits,
        isProteinOrFiber: category == "protein" || category == "fibers",
      ),
    ),
    child: Slider(
      value: value,
      max: max.toDouble(),
      onChanged: null,
    ),
  );
}
```

I tried calculating the value position with a custom function but I break my head trying to figure out the math:

```
double calculateInitialSliderPosition(double value, List<int> limits, int max) {
  // Find the index of the closest limit to the initial value
  int closestIndex = 0;
  double minDistance = (limits[0] - value).abs();

  for (int i = 1; i < limits.length; i++) {
    double distance = (limits[i] - value).abs();
    if (distance < minDistance) {
      minDistance = distance;
      closestIndex = i;
    }
  }

  // Calculate the position based on the closest limit index
double position = (max - limits[closestIndex]) / max;
return 1.0 - position;
}
```

Slider code:

```
class GradientRectSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape with BaseSliderTrackShape {
  const GradientRectSliderTrackShape({
    required this.limits,
    required this.isProteinOrFiber,
  });

  final List<int> limits;
  final bool isProteinOrFiber;

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    Offset? secondaryOffset,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalActiveTrackHeight = 2,
  }) {
    final canvas = context.canvas;
    final rect = Rect.fromPoints(
      Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy),
      Offset(parentBox.size.width, offset.dy + 15),
    );

    final itemSize = rect.width / (isProteinOrFiber ? 2 : 4);
    final dividerWidth = 1.0; // Adjust as needed
    final cornerRadius = 8.0; // Adjust as needed

    for (var i = 0; i < (isProteinOrFiber ? 2 : 4); i++) {
      final paint = Paint()
        ..color = getColorForIndex(i, isProteinOrFiber);

      final left = rect.left + (itemSize * i);
      final right = rect.left + (itemSize * (i + 1));

      RRect rRect;

      if (i == 0 && (isProteinOrFiber || !isProteinOrFiber)) {
        // First color (red for non-protein/fiber, or green for protein/fiber) with rounded left corners
        rRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromPoints(Offset(left, rect.top + 20), Offset(right, rect.bottom + 15)),
          topLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
        );
      } else if (i == (isProteinOrFiber ? 1 : 3)) {
        // Last color (green for non-protein/fiber) with rounded right corners
        rRect = RRect.fromRectAndCorners(
          Rect.fromPoints(Offset(left, rect.top + 20), Offset(right, rect.bottom + 15)),
          topRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
        );
      } else {
        // Colors in between with straight corners
        rRect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
          Rect.fromPoints(Offset(left, rect.top + 20), Offset(right, rect.bottom + 15)),
          Radius.zero,
        );
      }

      canvas.drawRRect(rRect, paint);

      // Draw dividers
      if (i < (isProteinOrFiber ? 1 : 3)) {
        final dividerPaint = Paint()
          ..color = Colors.grey; // Divider color

        final dividerRect = Rect.fromPoints(
          Offset(right, rect.top + 20),
          Offset(right + dividerWidth, rect.bottom + 15),
        );

        canvas.drawRect(dividerRect, dividerPaint);
      }
    }

    List<int> division = limits;

    for (var i = 0; i < division.length; i++) {
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(
          text: division[i].toString(),
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );

      textPainter.layout();
      double extraGap = i > 3 ? 10 : 5;
      textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(
          rect.left + (itemSize * i) - extraGap,
          rect.top + 35,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  Color getColorForIndex(int index, bool isProteinOrFiber) {
    if (isProteinOrFiber) {
      return index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.lightGreen;
    } else {
      switch (index) {
        case 0:
          return Colors.red;
        case 1:
          return Colors.orange;
        case 2:
          return Colors.lightGreen;
        case 3:
          return Colors.green;
        default:
          return Colors.green; // Default color
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you are trying to calculate the number as if all the limits have the same distance. Visually, it seems so, but, every limit has its own distance to the next. So, here is a function that can do that.

```
double calculateInitialSliderPosition(List<double> limits, double value){
  // Find the index of the closest minor (left) limit to the initial value
  late int initLimit;
  for(int i = 0; i < limits.length; i++){
    final bP = limits[i];
    if(bP <= value){
      initLimit = i;
    }else{
      break;
    }
  }
  /*
   * Have to take the two limits (left and right) around the value
   * let the line be the percentage of the line (0 to 1)
   * Then,
   *    * Calculate the position (percentage) of the left limit in the line
   *    * Calculate <<the distance>> from left limit position to the value position in the line 
   *      * let relative left limit be 0
   *      * let relative right limit be the distance between left limit to right limit
   *      * let relative value be the distance from left to value
   *      * Calculate the position (percentage) of relative value inside those two relative limits
   *      * Transform this relative position of value to <<the distance>> betwen absolute left limit
   *        to absolute value position in the line
   *    * sum (left limit position + distance of value from left limit) in order to obtain 
   *      the absolute position of value in the line
   */
  final initLimitLinePos = initLimit/limits.length;
  final relRightLimit = limits[initLimit + 1] - limits[initLimit];
  final relV = value - limits[initLimit];
  final relVPos = relV / relRightLimit;
  // 1/limits.length = the percentage of one limit with respect to the line
  final vFromInitPos = (1 / limits.length)*relVPos;
  return initLimitLinePos + vFromInitPos;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work it returns the same position for all sliders. I set   late int initLimit = 0; because I got an error that it's uninitialized.

Comment: i added the slider code

Comment: I proved it and it worked for me for disctinct limits and values. You just need to put as parameters the limits and the value you have (2.5 in your case), no need another variable, and the function calculate the exact value percentage in the line.

Comment: If initLimit throws uninitialized is because you're sorting the limits from major to minor. It will work only if the limits are sorted ascendingly. So, just make sure the limits order inside the function is ascendent.
The initLimit doesn't have to have an initial 0 value. It always will have a value at the final of the for, if the "value" is within the limits ranges.